# Use EC2 instance ID in wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have an autoscaling group launching different EC2 instances, each running the same wordpress application. Somewhere on the wordpress page (let's call it home.html), I want to show the EC2 instance id. I can grab the instance id using this curl command: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`.

Is there a way I can show the instance id using this curl command, or any way I can set an html variable dynamically to display this metadata on the page?

Comment: _"I can grab the instance id using this curl command: /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentytwentythree/templates."_ -Did you copy the wrong thing? That's a local file path to a default Wordpress theme templates forlder and has nothing to do with neither cURL command, or EC2 instance ids.

Comment: I didn't even notice. Thanks for that. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a HTTP request to GET any Metadata by passing the your metadata parameters.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

or

```
wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

You can find more meta-data [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html).

Comment: thanks, but is there a way I can translate this into an html variable so it shows up dynamically on my page?

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this in your PHP template where you want to display the instance ID:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id"); ?>
```

This will display the current instance id whenever the page is loaded